# Keras save intermediate variable

Tags: keras

I'm using Keras with tensorflow. And I want to see and save K.variable as numpy value during training. But "K.eval" don't work well. Is there any solution for that?

```
def acc(y_true, y_pred):
    temp = K.eval(y_true)
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: What do you mean 'don't work well'? What exactly have you tried and what are the results or error messages??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is accuracy during training you are after, Keras stores this info by default; if you fit your model like:

```
hist = model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=20,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

then training and validation accuracy & loss for each epoch are stored in the dictionary  `hist.history`:

```python
hist.history.keys()
# ['acc', 'loss', 'val_acc', 'val_loss']
hist.history['val_acc']  # validation accuracy
# [0.98140000000000005,
#  0.98340000000000005,
#  0.98740000000000006,
#  0.98680000000000001,
#  0.98750000000000004,
#  0.98740000000000006,
#  0.9869,
#  0.98939999999999995,
#  0.98819999999999997,
#  0.98819999999999997,
#  0.99039999999999995,
#  0.9889,
#  0.98919999999999997,
#  0.98860000000000003,
#  0.98780000000000001,
#  0.98799999999999999,
#  0.98819999999999997,
#  0.9889,
#  0.98909999999999998,
#  0.98609999999999998]
```